# Copy a cell from one part in a table to another

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

By copy I mean with formatting and everything attached. More importantly, I wish to be able to copy the fact that I am pasting 2 cells where one used to be (i.e. split cell).

Is there a way to do this elegantly in Word (rather than manually going through it all)?